# My SQL: How to make a trigger that inserts data to another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning JDBC and I'm trying to make a bank program. I'm using mySQL to make the database of the program which includes users and balance tables. I want to make a trigger that will automatically create data when data is inputted in the users table

So far i've made this code which doesn't work:

```
create trigger onInputUsers before insert on users 
for each row 
begin
insert into finances (id,balance,debt) values (null,0,0);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: The table structure of your tables is not provided, hence there is an assumption that there are columns as like `userid`, `balance` and `debt` in your tables.

There can be two triggers that can fulfil the requirement of yours (one that creates a record whenever there is a new user created and the other when a transaction is made by the user)!

This handles the creation of the audit entries for your record, which is not very much required (if you ask for my opinion)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER USER_FINANCE_TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT ON users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO finances (id, userid, balance, debt) VALUES (null, OLD.userid, 0, 0);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

This handles updating the `finances` table with the user activity:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER USER_FINANCE_UPDATE_TRIGGER BEFORE UPDATE ON balance 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO finances (id, userid, balance, debt) VALUES (null, OLD.userid, OLD.balance, OLD.debt);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Hope this answers your question well!

Comment: It worked! i just had to change some stuff for it to fit in my data base :D

Comment: @JobLipat, happy to help! Kindly upvote if you feel my answer helped you!